# Increment MySQL value on click with +1

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, get, increment

**What I have**

An url like this: `http://localhost:8888/website/?key=ABC`

A MySQL table with many rows, one with a key called `ABC`. I have a button that I want users to click (upvote) the MySQL row corresponding to `key=ABC`.

```
<a href="" onclick="increment()"></a>
```

In my **scripts.js** I have this (incomplete?) Ajax code:

```
function increment() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../js/ajax.php',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("function saved: " + data);
        }
    });
}
```

And my **ajax.php** looks like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['key']) {
        $rowKEYtest = $_GET['key'];
        $sql2 = "UPDATE database SET Score = Score + 1 WHERE UniqueKey = '$rowKEYtest'";
        $conn->query($sql2);
    } else {
        echo "lol";
    }
?>
```

It's not updating. I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look in your code, There is 2 mistakes.

```
1. In your ajax call you are using  type: 'POST', you should use GET.
2. You are nor parsing your 'key' param in ajax call.
```

Actually you are using POST method in ajax but in ajax.php trying to get the value with GET method. second thing you are not passing any param in ajax call.

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I can't solve it.. I have this code now:
`$("#vote-up-q").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '../js/ajax.php',
   data: {action: 'key'},
   success: function(data) {
    alert("function saved: " + data);
   }
  });
 });`